# Compilation fails using pygment/minted on texlive 2017

Tags: minted, pygments, texlive-2017

On Debian (testing) with texlive 2017.20170818-1, using "pdflatex --shell-escape mwe.tex" the following MWE does not compile:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{bw}
\definecolor{bg}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}
\setminted[text]{breaklines,fontsize=\footnotesize,bgcolor=bg}

\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{text}
  squirrel@t450s:~$ lspci
  00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI (rev 09)
  ...
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

The error message reads:

```
....
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]) (./_minted-mwe/default-pyg-prefix.pygstyle) (./_minted-mwe/bw.pygstyle)
! Undefined control sequence.
\minted@colorbg ...\OuterFrameSep }{0pt}\colorlet 
                                                  {shadecolor}{#1}\let \mint...
l.13 \end{minted}

?
```

Can anybody reproduce the problem? Is there a workaround? Deleting temporary files created by minted does not help. Versions installed by texlive are:

python-pygments:  2.2.0+dfsg-1
python3-pygments:  2.2.0+dfsg-1

Comment: Use xcolor instead of color.

Comment: Thanks, indeed, this solves the problem. It has been working with the color package for several years, so something must have been modified (more or less) recently. I would like to accept the answer, but can't as it is in a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce the error starting with TeXlive2016: From there on minted uses a command (\colorlet) that exists only in xcolor (and not in color), but doesn't load the package if it detects that color has been loaded. The best to get around the error is to load `xcolor` explicitly.

I suggest also that you make a bug report.

Answer (score 1):

Recent versions of `minted` require `xcolor` to use the `bgcolor` option, as a side effect of `bgcolor` now supporting page breaks.  I've fixed this in the [development version](https://github.com/gpoore/minted), so `bgcolor` will work with the `color` package starting with the next release (expected to be `minted` version 2.5.1).